# Set timeout for ajax in JQuery

Tags: ajax

I set timeout function for ajax connection but I'm getting in return 
as 'error' in statusText  instead of 'Timeout'

[image]

Comment: I believe the second parameter will be `"timeout"` in the event that the http error you are handling was a timeout type error (There are several HTTP error codes that correspond to a timeout).  Please could you post more code (regarding your timeout function)?

Comment: `function loadOutbox() {
  $.ajax({
   type : "GET",
   url : "/SwiftMail/loadOutbox.htm",
   datatype : "json",
   timeout : 90000,   
   error : function(x, t, m) {
    if (t === "Timeout") // instead I am getting as "error"
    {
     alert('request Timed out'); //to show Timed out error
    }
   }
  });`

Answer (score 0):

Possible values for the second argument (besides null) in your case "t" are "timeout", "error", "abort", and "parsererror".

The reason you are getting error as text status might be origin policy . Is it CORS request ?

Answer (score 0):

**An error must be occurring before the 90 seconds period has elapsed.**

To verify that you *can* capture timeouts, you could set the `timeout` value to something low, e.g:

```
function ajaxTest() { 
    $.ajax({ 
        type : "GET", 
        url : "http://www.google.com", 
        datatype : "json", 
        timeout : 1                                 //<-- Set to a low value
    }).done(function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {

        // Success
        alert('Success!');

    }).fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, err) {

        // Error
        alert('Failure! ' + textStatus);

    });
}
```

Extending the `timeout` to `90000` in the above is likely to throw a CORS error - since `http://www.google.com` is a different origin from yours (I assume!).

This is because the error is detected and processed before 90 seconds.

So therefore I assert that you have a separate error which is preventing your `timeout` handling from functioning as expected.